# Get a total of two different columns

Tags: sql

I need to get generate a combined total of two different columns.

My query looks like this

```
SELECT 0 AS OTHER_AMT, ABS([MISC AMT]*100) AS MISC_AMT FROM ESCHEATMENT_FINAL WHERE [TRAN DT] < '6/30/2012' AND [MISC AMT]<>0

UNION ALL

SELECT ABS([DEP AMT]*100+[INT AMT]*100) AS OTHER_AMT, 0 AS MISC_AMT FROM [CCC_Escheatment].[dbo].[ESCHEATMENT_FINAL] WHERE [TRAN DT] < '6/30/2014' AND [DEP AMT]<>0
```

I need a combined total amount for both MISC_AMT and OTHER_AMT .  How would I go about doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(other_amt) + sum(misc_amt) from (
    SELECT 0 AS OTHER_AMT, ABS([MISC AMT]*100) AS MISC_AMT FROM ESCHEATMENT_FINAL WHERE [TRAN DT] < '6/30/2012' AND [MISC AMT]<>0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ABS([DEP AMT]*100+[INT AMT]*100) AS OTHER_AMT, 0 AS MISC_AMT FROM [CCC_Escheatment].[dbo].[ESCHEATMENT_FINAL] WHERE [TRAN DT] < '6/30/2014' AND [DEP AMT]<>0
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it!